# Accessing this.model from inside $.get w/ Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, scope, mustache

I'm using [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org) for my app's templating system. I'm storing the templates in an external .html file inside of `<script></script>` blocks. Each script block has a unique ID that I am using to fetch out a template using jQuery.get().

So my render function for my view looks like this:

```
render: function(){
    $.get('templates/templates.html', function(templates) {
        try {
            var template = $(templates).filter('#tpl-MediaView').html();
            return mustache.render(template, this.model.toJSON());

            this.playlist.each(function(media) {
                var mediaView = new MediaView({model: media});
                this.$('#playlist').append(mediaView.render());
            });
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue I am having trouble with is accessing the `this.model.toJSON` from inside of the $.get(). I've tried assigning the value to a variable outside and passing it in. I've tryed running the return outside as well. I've also tried using $.ajax(). What is the easiest way to deal with this scope issue?

-- UPDATE --

I should add that the error I am receiving with this code is:

> Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

> Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined

It means `this.model` is returning undefined, which means `this` isn't what you think.  It's actually the global object, sadly.  Anytime you pass a function reference around, it will lose context.

> I've tried assigning the value to a variable outside and passing it in.

Have you? Because sounds right, and how this is typically done.

Usually you save `this` to local variable outside the enclosed function.  Then use that within the function instead of self.

```
render: function(){
    var self = this; // or some like "var that = this"
    $.get('templates/templates.html', function(templates) {
        //...
        self.model.toJSON()
        //...
    });
}
```

You can also `bind` functions to a specific context, though this is not fully supported on all browsers/runtimes.

```
render: function(){
    $.get('templates/templates.html', function(templates) {
        //...
        this.model.toJSON()
        //...
    }.bind(this));
}
```

---

And I know you didn't ask about CoffeeScript here, but if you feel like switching it has a seriously awesome feature for this problem.  The arrow `->` declares a normal function, but the fat arrow `=>` declares a bound function, which preserves whatever `this` was outside the function, basically doing the `var self = this` trick for you invisibly.  So this code here just works.

```
render: ->
    $.get 'templates/templates.html', (templates) =>
        # ...
        this.model.toJSON()
        # ...
```

Comment: Make sure that the 'this' in the enclosing function is right too.  If you call controller.render() it probably is, but if render is called in some funny way, like an event, it could be wrong.

Comment: Same error occurring. I know `this` is correct because it was working fine prior to externalizing the templates. Initially I set up the templates inside the view as strings. So basically the only thing that has changed is the addition of $.get() and moving everything inside of it.

Comment: Last comment made before your update. Reviewing your updated answer now. Will let you know.

Comment: That's a bad reason to assume what a variable is.  Sprinkle some `console.log(this)` in key places and see what `this` really is at the important spots of your code.

Comment: (1) I'm pretty sure `this` will be a jQuery AJAX context object, not `window` (but it still isn't the `this` that Valjas thinks it is). (2) `window` always has a [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) member so using `self` can lead to interesting bugs if you forget `var self = this`, `self` might not be the best name to use (unfortunately).

Comment: Also, since we're using backbone here, underscore's _.bind is available, as is _.bindAll. They can be used to bind methods that is cross-browser.